# CSS Writing mode facing left instead of right

Tags: html, css

I have a row of words in my html and i want to position the text vertically facing right.

On the image below, the 'saucers' word is facing the wrong way, but the 'charming' word is facing the right way. I achieved that through the following css:

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
transform: scale(-1)
```

However, the transform scale is making the 'charming' word stick out, and not be in line with the rest (see picture).

Is there an alternative way to make the word 'saucers' face the other way without using transform scale? Or just to make transform scale stay in line and not change position?

[image]

Comment: Yound can change the text direction with (1) and (-1) and the Right to left (transform-rl) and Left to right (transform-lr). 

 writing-mode: vertical-lr;
        transform: scale(1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using the same code:

```
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
transform: scale(-1)
```

And then as a workaround I removed the border on the div and moved it to the left slightly to keep it in line with the rest.